Boy working for the mafia to pay off his father's debt
This a movie about a boy being "raised" by an Albanian or Russian mafia. It's a large apartment complex or "projects" that all of these crooks live inside of. These projects also have hard working people in them who these mobsters loan money to. One of the people they loan money to is this boy's dad. His father could not pay the debt, so without his father knowing, he does side jobs for the crooks collecting money.
The most famous scene in the movie is where the boy knocks on a man's door and comes inside to talk about the money he owes the crooks. The man said he cannot pay so the 12 year old kid pulls out a black revolver and guns the man down in front of his wife and daughter, who is about the same age as the boy. At the end of the movie where the boy has now grown up and is a full time crook, he kills the boss that brought him into it all. It's a fat guy with a pony tail.  
The boy in the movie looks a lot like this:


I would say this movie was made in later years such as 2008 or so.
I think the movie was in Russian or Albanian with English subs, but I am not sure because the movie gave off such a foreign atmosphere. No American actors were in it so I believe it was in fact foreign. 


What does "a while back" actually mean - it can help us rule out more recent movies.  Also what does "in a different language but im NOT sure' mean - you were not sure which language, or not sure it was in a foreign language at all?

The movie is called Interview with a Hitman and was released in 2012.

Interview with a Hitman is a 2012 British action film[2] written and directed by Perry Bhandal. The film follows the life story of Viktor (Luke Goss), a professional Romanian hitman who talks about his own life and his path to become a hitman via interview with a local journalist. It was produced by Kirlian Pictures & Scanner Rhodes with the assistance of Northern Film & Media. The film stars Luke Goss, Caroline Tillette, Stephen Marcus, Danny Midwinter and Elliot Greene.

